# OSM direct tile referencing.

Tags: html, notifications, openstreetmap

I wanted to display a map in HTML5 notification. Since notifications do not allow a full fledged HTML+JS app to run inside them, I wanted to show just an image.

The question is how do I get the link to the appropriate map tile image if I know the lat/lon co-coordinates. I can set some fixed values for zoom level etc. I don't wan't to run my own tile server or depend on third party servers (other than openstreetmaps.org) that may go down any time. I am okay with the lack of ability to customize image size, or centering image around the co-ordinate etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of example conversions from lat/long to tile number in various langauges on [this OSM wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) - hopefully you'll find something there that you can use.